# UIButton addTarget to method of another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, iphone-sdk-3.0, selector

I am adding a UIButton using coding and assigning target to the method of other class
I try the following code but not works for me.

**one class**

```
-(void)myMethod{
//some code
    SEL myFunction = @selector(myFunction:);
    [obj refresh:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:self,@"target",circleBtnAct,@"action",nil]
                  action:circleBtnAct];
    [addContactView addSubview:myWorldView];
//some code
}
-(IBAction)myFunction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"... %d",[sender tag]);
}
```

**second class**

```
-(void)refresh:(id)sender action:(SEL)action{
//some code
    [btn addTarget:[sender objectForKey:@"target"] action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
//some code
}
```

even I also tried 
`[btn addTarget:[sender objectForKey:@"target"] action:[sender objectForKey:@"action"] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];`

But its not working .. application crashes on the line `addTarget`

*It works fine if I create class one object in class second and then use this line*
`[btn addTarget:oneObj action:@selector(myFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];`

Comment: What does the crash log say? Can you add it?

Comment: thanks Deepak Solved .. silly mistake I was passing non-object value in Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys silly mistake

I was passing non-object value in Dictionary

Now using this Dictionary
`[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:self,@"target",[NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(circleBtnAct:)],@"action",nil]`

```
-(void)myMethod{
//some code
    SEL myFunction = @selector(myFunction:);
    [obj refresh:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:self,@"target",[NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(circleBtnAct:)],@"action",nil]
                  action:circleBtnAct];
    [addContactView addSubview:myWorldView];
//some code
}
```

**second class**

```
-(void)refresh:(id)sender action:(SEL)action{
//some code
    [btn addTarget:[sender objectForKey:@"target"] action:[[sender objectForKey:@"action"] pointerValue] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
//some code
}
```

Thanks All